# ASP.NET MVC 5 Conditional Validation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following form model:

```
public class Form {
    public string Field1;
    public string Field2;

    public Applicant PrimaryApplicant;
    public Applicant SecondaryApplicant;
}

public class Applicant {
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a first name"), Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName;
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a last name"), Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName;
}
```

The primary applicant is always required while second applicant is optional, unless any of it's fields is set.

I've tried implementing it using IValidatbleObject interface and Validate method but it doesn't work. (ModelState.IsValid was still returning false)

```
    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var validationResult = new List<ValidationResult>();

        foreach (var property in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this).Cast<PropertyDescriptor>())
        {
            Validator.TryValidateValue(property.GetValue(this), validationContext, validationResult, property.Attributes.OfType<ValidationAttribute>());
        }

        var validationCount = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this)
                                        .Cast<PropertyDescriptor>()
                                        .Count(p => p.Attributes.OfType<ValidationAttribute>().Any());

        if (!IsPrimaryApplicant && validationResult.Count() == validationCount) validationResult.Clear();

        return validationResult;
    }
```

How to do validation in this type of scenario?

Comment: did you solve this problem?

Comment: I don't work for that company anymore but if I remember correctly we had to write a custom model binder.

Comment: @Stefan Szakal Any tips on how you handled client side validation?